# Contenteditable div height limit

Tags: php, css, html, contenteditable

Hey guys I have problems with contenteditable height. With code like this:

```js
 function Preview() {
 var x = document.getElementById("code").value;
 document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = x;
}
```

```css
  .preview{
text-align: left;
color: white;
margin-left: 10px;
max-height: 300px;
overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<section id="main"> 
   <div id="gra"> 
      <input type="hidden" id="current-code" name="current-code" />
         <textarea id="code" name="code">
             <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html lang="en">
                  <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>A Simple PHP File</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                    <h1><?php echo "Hello, world!"; ?></h1>
                  </body>
               </html> 
             </textarea>
       <div class="flex">
          <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="Preview()">Preview</a>
         <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="Reset()">Reset</a>  
       </div>
      </div>
      <div id="gra">
        <div contenteditable="true" class="preview" id="preview">  
      </div>
    </div>
 </section>
```

When I enter code with more  I can observe effect like this:
[image: test]

Anyone can help me with limit contenteditable height?

Comment: If you only need to hide the overflowing text, you can just set `overflow: hidden` via CSS. If you really need to limit the number of lines, you'll have to use JavaScript in order to do so. Please don't expect others to do the work for you, but rather start trying it on your own and keep coming back whenever you hit specific problems in your code.

Comment: You can add scrollbar with css `overflow-y: scroll;` or to hide it as @Connum said.

Comment: `overflow: hidden` would hide the remainder of his code. I guess `overflow: auto` would be more appropriate

Comment: @MarkLenon thanks, overflow-y works:) thank You very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

and also change `color: red;` instead of `color:white` because its not see anything on white screen

```js
function Preview() {

  var x = document.getElementById("code").value;
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = x;
}

function Reset() {
  document.getElementById("preview").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
.preview {
  text-align: left;
  color: red;
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

```html
<section id="main">
  <div id="gra">
    <input type="hidden" id="current-code" name="current-code" />
    <textarea id="code" name="code">
             <!DOCTYPE html>
               <html lang="en">
                  <head>
                    <meta charset="UTF-8">
                    <title>A Simple PHP File</title>
                  </head>
                  <body>
                    <h1><?php echo "Hello, world!"; ?>you write php code hear so it will not print on html</h1>
                  </body>
               </html> 
             </textarea>
    <div class="flex">
      <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="Preview()">Preview</a>
      <a href="#" class="myButton" onclick="Reset()">Reset</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="gra">
    <div contenteditable="true" class="preview" id="preview">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: so simple overflow-y made the thing:)